# Selecting all checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I simply want to check all of the check boxes on a page if a user clicks the "Select All" button.

In the body:

```
<button id="checkall">Select All</button>
```

jQuery:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkall').click(function () {
            $("input[type=checkbox]").each( function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

And the checkboxes are generated by a little bit of php:

```
echo '<li>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
echo '</li>';
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You dont need the each statement.  Just select all checkboxes and set the property `checked = true`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Note [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a feature added to 1.6 and up.  If you are on a version of jQuery prior to 1.6 you will need the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: bear in mind this will only check the boxes.  Additional code will be necessary for unchecking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting checkbox with tag name better assign it some class and select it with classname

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#checkall').click(function () {
           $(".checkbox").each( function(i,chkbox) {
             $(chkbox).attr('checked', true);
      });
     });
   });
```

php code

```
                 echo '<li>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                echo '</li>';
```

Comment: This still has one `});` too few, and `.each` is kind of redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss a `});` for the `.each(function(){}` statement! There was no error else!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            // or 
            // $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }); // you missed this one!!!
    });
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.each()` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work, Short and handy Code

```
<script>
    $('#check_all').click(function () {
    $( this ).closest('form').find(':checkbox').prop( 'checked' , this.checked ? true : false );
})
</script>
```